# How to set up Camera Unity

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

Someone can help me to create a camera like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fIoxtJ_FK4&feature=youtu.be&t=1m24s

I know that, they used gyroscope to do this. However, I don't know How did they do with the camera

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about gyroscopes and cameras.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man I mean I just want to know How to set-up camera like this.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. I assume you refer to the first minutes of the video. Do you want to know how they move the camera according to the phone movement, or do you want to achieve the stereoscopic effect. If it is related to the camera, from unity you can read the gyroscope data and then just apply the proper movement on the camera on the XYZ axis. You can set your camera initially in an orthographic fashion and then move it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the rotation rate or the attitude of the gyroscope. Just update the rotation of your camera based on the gyro. Here is an example code how it could be done.

```
void Start() 
{
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
}

void Update() 
{
    rotationRate = Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased;
    angle.x += -rotationRate.x * ROTATION_SPEED;
    angle.y += -rotationRate.y * ROTATION_SPEED;
    Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles = angle;
}
```

The documentation can be found here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html